# At what stage in an English registry office ceremony do two people become legally married?

Tags: marriage, united-kingdom

Is it after they've both said the vows and the registrar has pronounced them man and wife, or after the legal registry has been signed? Or some other time?

Comment: Ah, the old *Princess Bride* argument: Does it require the bride to say, "I do?"  Or does it merely require the Impressive Clergyman to [say "Man and wife?"](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/37de24ed-19c2-4e86-bba8-48cc1925d290)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not worthy of an answer, but I don't have enough points to comment.

When my sister married her husband, after being pronounced man and wife but before signing the register, the husband joked that he still had time to escape as he hadn't signed the register yet. The registrar replied "It's not signing the register that makes you married. It's me saying you're married that makes you married."